# Регистрация php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[image: вот раздел Network]Есть 2 файла: auth.php  и  auth-file.php. В первом файле стандартная форма:

```
<form action="auth-file.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login" placeholder="Введите ваш логин"><br>
      <input type="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Введите имя и фамилию"><br>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Введите пароль"><br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"></button>
    </form>
```

Второй файл обрабатывает эту форму и заполняет таблицу в базе данных. Возникла проблема в перенаправлении. 
При успешной регистрации, файл **auth-file.php** должен отправлять пользователя на, допустим, **index.php**. 
Знаю, что можно это сделать через 
`header(Location:***)`. 
Не получается. 
После нажатия кнопки, страница уходит вникуда. Вот код, который направляет ее вникуда. 
`header("Location: index.php")`. 
Помогите разобраться, где я ошибся, пожалуйста

Comment: что значит вникуда? откройте вкладку Сеть в панели разработчика бразуера и отправьте форму. Посмотрите какой код ответа пришел. 301 - редиект был. 200 - без редиректа.

Comment: Код ошибки 500, по идее

Comment: включите отображение ошибок, или смотрите логи.

Comment: Добавил скриншот с разделом Network

Comment: == Код ошибки 500, по идее ==  Ошибка в файле auth-file.php - ищите.